# How will require.js work with http2 in the future?

Tags: requirejs, http2

When building an app, the most ideal thing is to lazy load modules, but also to download them as batch 1 file, as you require them. Require.js supports async lazy loading, but not as batch, but http2 supports batch. Will they unify at some point in the future?

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: Why would the W3C or WHATWG want to unify with require.js written by "some guy" (with due respect)? Not everyone wants, needs or uses it.

Comment: I mean, will require.js support the use of batch download in http2 in the future?

Comment: It is not requirejs specifically but the AMD protocol and ES modules that will naturally benefit from http2.  Using the typescript compiler to generate AMD modules and using requirejs to load them is a powerful solution in the age of http2; a solution that works without rollup, webpack or babel.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP/2 does not have "batch" download, as it is not able to batch together multiple files for download automagically.

What HTTP/2 has over HTTP/1.1 is multiplexing and HTTP/2 Push.

With multiplexing, clients such as browsers may perform an almost unlimited number of concurrent requests - while with HTTP/1.1 they could perform only typically 6 concurrent requests.

With HTTP/2 Push, a server is able to push to the client multiple resources associated with a primary resource.

Multiplexing is built-in in the protocol, so it requires no configuration on either the client or the server.
HTTP/2 Push requires to be configured on the server.

`require.js` will benefit from both these features of HTTP/2, but it's not that `require.js` needs to "support" them.

When `require.js` makes a HTTP request to download a module, that will appear as a normal HTTP request.
If `require.js` needs to download 10+ modules, with HTTP/1.1 it would have made those requests but the browser infrastructure would have been able to  make only 6 of those request concurrently and then it would have waited for some request to be responded before sending more requests; with HTTP/2 all requests can be made concurrently.

With HTTP/2 Push, `require.js` may make the request for one module, and the server may figure out that it will also need N other modules (the server will learn the request pattern from previous requests, or have a configuration that tells it what the other modules are), and the server will HTTP/2 Push the other modules to the client.

In both cases, `require.js` will just automatically benefit from the upgrade to HTTP/2.